# ASP.Net MVC File Upload via Bootstrap Modal Dialog results redirect browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm having  a basic form with few text fields and a file upload controller on a bootstrap modal dialog (Bootstrap 4). below is my code:

Model:

```
public class DemoContent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression("([0-9]+)",ErrorMessage = "Age must be numbers only")]
    public int Age { get; set; }

    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
    [Display(Name = "Image")]
    public HttpPostedFileBase ImageUrl { get; set; }

}
```

JavaScript

```
  $(function() {
        $("a[data-modal=demoPopup]").on("click", function () {
            $("#demoModalContent").load(this.href, function () {
                $("#demoModal").modal({ keyboard: true }, "show");

                $("#demoForm").submit(function () {

                    if ($("#demoForm").valid()) {

                        var files = $("ImageUrl").get(0).files;
                        var data = $(this).serialize();
                        data.append("ImageUrl", files[0]);

                        $.ajax({
                            url: this.action,
                            type: this.method,
                            data: $(this).serialize(),
                            success: function (result) {
                                if (result.success) {
                                    $("#demoModal").modal("hide");
                                    location.reload();
                                } else {
                                    $("#MessageToClient").text(result.message);
                                }
                            },
                            error: function () {
                                $("#MessageToClient").text("The web server had an error.");
                            }
                        });
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            });
            return false;
        });
```

Controller:

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(DemoContent model)
    {
        if (model.Age > 55)
        {
            var file = model.ImageUrl;
            return Json(new { success = true });
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(new { success = false,message="Invalid Data" });
        }
    }
```

Now when i open the popup it works also when i submit the form it goes to the controller along with the file. but the problem is once the server returns the success message the popup shows that message in a blank page instead of capturing it and refreshing the current page or showing the messages. any idea why is this happening.

link to source files : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1W3H3kFEpHJWfaf7_UnJI3O5I900GxyC7

Comment: try adding `$("#demoForm").submit(function (e) { e.preventDefault` This must be your case

Comment: @Rajan nope it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

May be you wrote your javascripts function in document.ready() function,That is why it again refreshing.

Answer (score 0):

Write your JavaScript code as follows:

```
$(function() {
        $("a[data-modal=demoPopup]").on("click", function () {
            $("#demoModalContent").load(this.href, function () {
                $("#demoModal").modal({ keyboard: true }, "show");

                $("#demoForm").submit(function (event) { // Pass the event as parameter to the function.

                    event.preventDefault(); // I have added these two lines
                    event.stopImmediatePropagation();

                    if ($("#demoForm").valid()) {

                        var files = $("ImageUrl").get(0).files;
                        var data = $(this).serialize();
                        data.append("ImageUrl", files[0]);

                        $.ajax({
                            url: this.action,
                            type: this.method,
                            data: $(this).serialize(),
                            success: function (result) {
                                if (result.success) {
                                    $("#demoModal").modal("hide");
                                    location.reload();
                                } else {
                                    $("#MessageToClient").text(result.message);
                                }
                            },
                            error: function () {
                                $("#MessageToClient").text("The web server had an error.");
                            }
                        });
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            });
            return false;
        });
```

Comment: May be you forgot to pass the event as parameter to the function in the sumit() event.

Comment: Nope its says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of undefined"

Comment: here is the exact issue replicated https://drive.google.com/open?id=1W3H3kFEpHJWfaf7_UnJI3O5I900GxyC7

Answer (score -1):

I think you should install and use Microsoft.Unobtrusive.Validation and *.Ajax, if you want your modal to be updated (I get your question like that...). With this, you can use code like the following example, which can update your modal (used this in a project a few days ago):

Modal:

```
        @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Login", new { Controller = "Home", area = "" }, new AjaxOptions() { OnSuccess = "onSuccessLogin", HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "loginmodalbody"}, new { id = "loginForm" }))
        {
            <div class="modal-body" id="loginmodalbody">
                <div class="text-danger loginfailed"></div>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="card border-primary mb-3" style="margin: 0 auto;">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/Modals/LoginModalBody.cshtml")                           
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="container">
                        <span><a onclick="alert('Leads to pw info')" href="#">Forgot password?</a></span>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block buttonlogin">Login</button>
                </div>                                      
                <br />
            </div>
        }
```

Modal Body:

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-12">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EMail, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "EMail", @id = "inputemail" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EMail, "", new { @class = "text-danger", @id = "dangeremail" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-12">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Passwort", @id = "inputpassword" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger", @id = "dangerpassword" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thus, it updates your modal body after getting data from the posting of the form - you define the id to be updated within the AjaxOptions, as shown in the above snippet.

Comment: actually i need the page to refresh on success. updating the model n others work fine for me now